# remove second exact observation in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this: I want to remove rows where there are partial duplicates. Here is sample data. I want row 4 to be removed as there is overlap between row 3. In other words, when there is a numerical value in one row, I want to remove rows where that same numeric value is presented with an underscore and the same numeric value.

```
df1
           id     v1       v2
54        10119 0.246659 0.247789 
55        10124 0.245777 0.247530 
56        10127 0.246811 0.247849
57  10127_10127 0.246788 0.247853 
58  10203_10203 0.246788 0.247853
```

This is what I want.

```
df1
           id     v1       v2
54        10119 0.246659 0.247789 
55        10124 0.245777 0.247530 
56        10127 0.246811 0.247849
58  10203_10203 0.246788 0.247853
```

I tried using "grep" to remove values with an underscore but that's removing all IDs with an underscore. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(col = id, into = c('id1','id2'), sep = '_', remove = F) %>% 
filter(!duplicated(id1)) %>% select(-c(id1,id2))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id             v1    v2
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 10119       0.247 0.248
2 10124       0.246 0.248
3 10127       0.247 0.248
4 10203_10203 0.247 0.248
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  id             v1    v2
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 10119       0.247 0.248
2 10124       0.246 0.248
3 10127       0.247 0.248
4 10127_10127 0.247 0.248
5 10203_10203 0.247 0.248
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `regmatches` to extract the last five digits and `duplicated` to find duplicate values:

```
duplicated(regmatches(df1$id, gregexpr('\\d+$', df1$id)))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Inverting `duplicated` to drop duplicate row:

```
df1[!duplicated(regmatches(df1$id, gregexpr('\\d+$', df1$id))), ]

            id       v1       v2
54       10119 0.246659 0.247789
55       10124 0.245777 0.247530
56       10127 0.246811 0.247849
58 10203_10203 0.246788 0.247853
```

Data for `df1`

```
structure(list(id = c("10119", "10124", "10127", "10127_10127", 
"10203_10203"), v1 = c(0.246659, 0.245777, 0.246811, 0.246788, 
0.246788), v2 = c(0.247789, 0.24753, 0.247849, 0.247853, 0.247853
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `duplicated` and `strsplit`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(sapply(strsplit(id, "_"), `[`, 1)))
#            id       v1       v2
#54       10119 0.246659 0.247789
#55       10124 0.245777 0.247530
#56       10127 0.246811 0.247849
#58 10203_10203 0.246788 0.247853
```